# How to attach a group by column to a main dataframe without merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 101, 101, 101],
     'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE02',
                   'CSE02', 'CSE02'],
     'ques_date' : ['13/11/2020', '10/1/2018','11/11/2017', '27/03/2016', 
                '13/05/2010',  '10/11/2008','11/1/2007', '27/02/2006'],
     'resp_date' : [np.nan, '11/1/2018','14/11/2017', '29/03/2016', 
                np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,'28/02/2006'],
     'marks' : [77, 86, 55, 90, 
                65, 90, 80, 67]}
)
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(['stud_id','sub_code','ques_date'],inplace=True)
```

I would like to compute the `mean difference` between `ques_date` for each `stud_id` and `sub_cod` and store it in a new column.

So, I tried the below

```
df['next_ques_date'] = df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code'])['ques_date'].shift(-1)
df['backlog_wish_req_diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['next_ques_date'], dayfirst=True) - pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True)).dt.days
tdf = df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code'],as_index=False)['backlog_wish_req_diff'].mean().rename(columns={'backlog_wish_req_diff':'backlog_wish_req_mean_days'})
(df.merge(tdf, left_on=['stud_id','sub_code'], right_on=['stud_id','sub_code'],
                            suffixes=('', '_y')))
```

Though the output is correct, I would like to attach the `backlog_wish_req_mean_days` column to `df` directly after groupby. I don't like to do merge to link it back with `df` (from `tdf`)

Is there any efficient and elegant approach to do this? without merge?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['backlog_wish_req_mean_days']=(df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code'])['backlog_wish_req_diff']
                                    .transform('mean'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   stud_id sub_code  ques_date   resp_date  marks next_ques_date  \
3      101    CSE01 2016-03-27  29/03/2016     90     2017-11-11   
2      101    CSE01 2017-11-11  14/11/2017     55     2018-01-10   
1      101    CSE01 2018-01-10   11/1/2018     86     2020-11-13   
0      101    CSE01 2020-11-13         NaN     77            NaT   
7      101    CSE02 2006-02-27  28/02/2006     67     2007-01-11   
6      101    CSE02 2007-01-11         NaN     80     2008-11-10   
5      101    CSE02 2008-11-10         NaN     90     2010-05-13   
4      101    CSE02 2010-05-13         NaN     65            NaT   

   backlog_wish_req_diff  backlog_wish_req_mean_days  
3                  594.0                       564.0  
2                   60.0                       564.0  
1                 1038.0                       564.0  
0                    NaN                       564.0  
7                  318.0                       512.0  
6                  669.0                       512.0  
5                  549.0                       512.0  
4                    NaN                       512.0
```

Comment: @TheGreat - it is duplicate, so comunuity wiki answer.

Comment: @TheGreat - I think not necesary, it is up to you.

Comment: @TheGreat - If want delete, I can remove answer. It is up to you.